# Set datetime timezone when posting data via JSON api

Tags: 8

I'm using core JSON api to POST/PATCH data from an Android App to my Drupal 8 site. When I need to fill a datetime field I use the next JSON, for example, 2020-02-20T13:15:00. But with this format, this time is UTC, but I need Europe/Madrid timezone. How should I do it?

Comment: All dates are stored in UTC within Drupal, so you should be sending the API UTC dates. So it sounds like you probably need to convert your date into UTC within your app before sending to drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DateTimeNormalizer`, the inferface format is RFC3339, which is `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP` as an input format string.  It also accepts the ISO8601 PHP string, which is `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO`

Try using strings like in your request '2020-02-20T13:15:00+01:00'.

What I suspect is happening, is that since you aren't specifying the UTC offset, it is being interpreted as '+00:00'

The denormalizer also allepts a [format string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) with the request to parse the `value`.  I believe it is called `format`

See also `DateTimeNormalizerTest` and `EntityTestDatetimeTest` for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and I'll check it if it works.

Comment: I have a question. In Spain we have two timezone. In winter +1h but in summer +2h (we have to add an hour the next March, 29). Then, should I post +2:00 in summer and +01:00 in winter?

Comment: @briast The proper way is to generate a date/time object on the host that is doing the post and then render it out in the proper format, which will then append the proper offset string.  In PHP it would be something like `$value = $date->format('c')` or `$value = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to do it in my android App.